# ¿como pongo un contador que pegue datos en filas continuas?

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo una macro que me retira diferentes celdas de una hoja y me las pega en otra en forma de fila ordenada, el problema es que los datos de la primera hoja "TEMAS VIDEO C." se iran cambiando manualmente y al ejecutar la macro debe registrar una fila mas abajo de la anterior en la hoja 2 "Registro VIDEO C."

La Macro está guardando correctamente los datos pero no se como hacer para que cada vez que guarde lo haga en la fila de abajo y no en la misma siempre. La variable que estoy usando para las filas es "VFILAS" que empieza desde la "3". imagino que seria algo como VFILAS+1 al final pero no se como ponerlo. gracias

```
Sub CopiarCeldas_VIDEO_C()
Dim VFILAS As Integer
VFILAS = 3

Range("c6").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("B" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c7").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("c" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c8").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("d" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c9").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("e" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c10").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("f" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c11").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("g" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c12").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("h" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c13").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("i" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c14").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("j" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c15").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("k" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c16").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("l" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c17").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("m" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c18").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("n" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c19").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("o" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c20").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("p" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c21").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("q" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c22").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("r" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c23").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("s" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c24").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("t" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("h6").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("u" & VIFLAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("h8").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("v" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("h10").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("w" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Activate
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Necesito ayuda para poner un contador en MACRO EXCEL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/381483/necesito-ayuda-para-poner-un-contador-en-macro-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes conocer cuantas filas tiene un rango con la propiedad:

```
.Rows.Count
```

Si quieres escribir una fila más abajo es tan simple como sumar 1.