# Necesito ayuda para poner un contador en MACRO EXCEL

Tags: excel

El problema es el siguiente, tengo un formulario en una hoja que se irá llenando manualmente cada 10min aproximadamente, y cada vez que se llene tiene un botón con macro que copia los datos ingresados y los envía a otra hoja como registro, el problema es que me registra siempre en la misma fila y necesito poner un contador que haga que cada vez que se registre la información sume "1" a la fila de modo que la proxima vez que se ejecute la macro grabe en la fila siguiente. la variable que estoy usando para las filas es "VFILAS" pero no se como auto-aumentar cada vez que se use la macro. imagino que será algo como VFILAS=VFILAS+1 al final de la macro pero no me funciona por ningun lado no se que me falta. agradezco su ayuda.

Comparto el codigo:

```
Sub CopiarCeldas_VIDEO_C()

Dim VFILAS As Integer

Dim VARIABLE As Integer

VFILAS = 3 + VARIABLE
VARIABLE = VARIABLE + 1

Range("c6").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("B" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c7").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("c" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c8").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("d" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("c9").Copy
Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Range("e" & VFILAS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.").Activate

Selection.Offset(1, 0).Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que las variables se reinician cada vez que ejecutas el código desde cero. Entonces tu variable `VFILAS` siempre va a valer lo mismo, y por lo tanto, sobreescribes.

Sin embargo en VBA se puede calcular siempre el número de la última fila con datos (puedes mirar en Google sobre ello, es **muy** util).

He adaptado tu código. Simplemente he añadido una variable que calcula la última fila con datos, y le suma uno antes de pegar los datos.

Pruébalo y nos cuentas.

```
Sub CopiarCeldas_VIDEO_C()

Dim UF As Long 'Usamos esta variable para calcular la última fila con datos

With Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.")
    UF = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'esto siempre devolverá la última fila no vacía en la columna B
    
    Range("c6").Copy
    .Range("B" & UF + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Range("c7").Copy
    .Range("c" & UF + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    Range("c8").Copy
    .Range("d" & UF + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    Range("c9").Copy
    .Range("e" & UF + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With


End Sub
```

Por cierto, si lo único que quieres es llevarte **el valor** de una celda a otra, independientemente del formato, no hace falta copiar y pegar valores, sino que puedes mover el valor directamente. De hecho, tu código se podría simplificar así:

```
Sub CopiarCeldas_VIDEO_C()

Dim UF As Long 'Usamos esta variable para calcular la última fila con datos

With Worksheets("Registro VIDEO C.")
    UF = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'esto siempre devolverá la última fila no vacía en la columna B
    .Range("B" & UF + 1 & ":E" & UF + 1) = Range("C6:C9").Value 'nos llevamos todos los valores
End With


End Sub
```

Así estaría optimizado y tardaría menos.

Answer (score 0):

La solución ya la tienes, solo comentarte que tu suposición de `VFILAS=VFILAS+1` ó `VARIABLE = VARIABLE + 1` no funcionan porque cada vez que finaliza la ejecución de la macro las variables VFILAS y VARIABLE o cualquier otra variable de la macro desaparecen y sus valores se pierden.

Al ejecutarse otra vez la macro, estas variables toman los valores de inicio de nuevo.

Este tipo de variables se llaman **variables locales** las cuales solo "viven" durante la ejecución de una función (es lo que es una macro simple como esta).